# Syntax Error Php (for-loop)

Tags: php, image, loops, for-loop, syntax-error

This is the only code messing up the php, I removed it and it resumes perfecty, so I am guessing something within this loop statement is wrong; can someone please see whats wrong?

The below suppose to search the folder and see if the image is already within that folder, if so it chnges the $i by +1 each time ($i++) and then checks again with a max of 30 number.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?
Error I Get:

```
"HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while     the server was attempting to fulfill the request"
```

So must be something within the code not configured correctly

-Php Loop Code

```
<?php

define ("MAX_SIZE","100"); 


 function getExtension($str) {
     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; }
     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
     return $ext;
 }


 $errors=0;
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
 {

$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

if ($image) 
{

    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);


 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") &&     ($extension != "gif")) 
    {

//print error message

echo "";

        $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {

$size=filesize(['image']['tmp_name']);

if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
echo "";

$errors=1;
}

 $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;



//Error Occurs Below
for($i=0; $i<30; $i++)
{
$relativePath="members/image/corey/"."photo".$i;
if(!file_exists($relativePath)) {
    continue;
}
    else
{
    $newNumber=$i;
    break;
}
}
$fileName=$_FILES["name"]."$newNumber";
$relativePath="members/image/corey/".$filename.'.'.$extension;
move_uploaded_file($image, $relativePath);

//Error Occurs Above
?>
```

-Buttons

```
    <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="">
  <table>
  <tr><td><table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="Submit" id="upload" type="submit" value="Upload image" onclick"load_images()" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td></tr>
  </table>      
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I've undone your last destructive edit. Do not attempt to "close" questions this way.

Comment: Ok, My bad. I have flagged it also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing "}" to match the opening one for your `for` loop.

Comment: where should this be located?  the bottom 3 lines are not apart of the loop.

Comment: oh common...this is just a syntax errror...this is not a place for syntax errors....just put a closing brace before the last 3 lines.

Comment: Check all the code again, I fixed the syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the closing brace for the "for" loop at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

In that snippet you are missing a closing }

Answer (score 1):

`$["FILES"]["name"]`? You're missing the variable name. It should be something along the lines of `$_FILES['file']['name']`

Also, [move_uploaded_file](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) takes two arguments: a source and a destination. Something like:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['temp_name'], $relativePath);
```

Comment: I do have that variables, this is not all the code

Comment: So you expect us to debug "fake" code? Which other parts of your posted code aren't real?

Comment: I changed to your according but still a error

Comment: there I editted all of the code.